# HTML5 Canvas performance is slow on few android mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-canvas

I have a chart developed using HTML5 canvas, which performs okay on **Nexus 5**, but very poorly on a similar range device **LG G3**.

As we followed most of the best practices to implement chart, and LG G3 has very high resolution (1440x2560 pixels, around 558dpi); so to improve performance on it, I rendered the canvas in low resolution.
But it doesn't help much.

http://www.smashcat.org/av/canvas_test/

The above test runs on

- Desktop Chrome with around 240 fps
- iPhone 6 with around 180 fps
- Nexus 5 with around 108 fps
- LG G3 with around 69 fps

And the same test with lower resolution (half of original):
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/QXNTi2OmAEFp8vDM2dwM/

- Nexus 5 with around 140 fps
- LG G3 with around 80 fps

I wanted LG G3 to at least reach the Nexus 5 numbers with low resolution, However it doesn't.

So my question is, what else I can do to improve the canvas performance on LG G3 or similar performing devices?
I am not looking for any suggestion like, use multiple canvas or code best practices or canvas best practices (avoid fillText, use fillRect etc.) as I already followed those.

Comment: Did you used setInterval or setTimer? use requestAnimationFrame instead. Performance will increase significantly.

Comment: I am using requestAnimationFrame in my original chart.

Comment: then I recommend that reads these articles: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript  http://desalasworks.com/article/javascript-performance-techniques/  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/

Comment: @modernator, thanks for the links, seems to be helpful. Though I am yet to read all those.